# Opening JQuery dialog shifts background

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

Here you click on the video thumbnails and the dialogs open fine, but when they do, the background/page shifts to the right slightly. Is there a way to make this smooth?

http://go.xifin.com/Feel-Like-You-Cant-Catch-Up.html

I read that a vertical scrollbar shifts the page and confirmed that overflow-y:scroll removes the shift, but then the background and video scroll. What I need is
1) a horiz/vert. centered video over a fixed/non-scrolling background (as currently) that also
2) does not shift when opened.

Possible?

Comment: Oh I just realized that my link pointed to an older version of the page. If you have any ideas, please use the link again.

Comment: OK I removed the shift with a margin-left
`$('#outerWrapDiv').css('margin-left','-9px');`

and then on close set it back
`$('#outerWrapDiv').css('margin-left','0');`

Does anyone foresee any issues with this?

Comment: Mobile. :) Causes issues for me.